# How to correctly write module in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to make it so I don't have to have multiple connections to my database when I can just put my connection and runQuery function in a file and just require it in another file. Here is what I have in my "mysql.js" file.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = function () {
    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: '------',
        user: 'voltclou_site',
        password: '----',
        database: process.env.database
    })

    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('[DATABASE] Error connecting: ' + err.stack);
            return;
        }
        console.log('[DATABASE] Connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
    });

    async function runQuery(query, values) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.query(query, values, function (error, results) {
                if (error) return reject(error)
                return resolve(results)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Here is how I would like to require it in my files:

```
const { connection, runQuery } = require('./functions/mysql')
```

Am I doing this correctly? I'm new to this whole module thing. I've been trying to split my files up because one index.js with 3000+ lines is insane. Thanks for any help.

Comment: No, you need to remove your current `module.exports = function() { .keep this body at tope level..}` and add, at the botom of the file, `module.exports = {connection, runQuery};`

Comment: Note that you've shared login details here. If that password is in use anywhere I recommend you change it now.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I just changed the password to the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you didnt do it correclty. What you have done you have exported it as an default but you want to export named functions. You can do it like:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "81.19.215.6",
  user: "voltclou_site",
  password: "yogO{6,F@8WS",
  database: process.env.database
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error("[DATABASE] Error connecting: " + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log("[DATABASE] Connected as id " + connection.threadId);
});

async function runQuery(query, values) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(query, values, function(error, results) {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      return resolve(results);
    });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  connection,
  runQuery
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you've described, `{ connection, runQuery }`, should be the value assigned to `module.exports`:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

let connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... });
connection.connect(...);
let runQuery = async (query, values) => { ... };

module.exports = { connection, runQuery };
```

You may not even need to export `connection`, if all you need elsewhere is `runQuery`!